# Angular 4.3 - Correct Way to Implement an Enum in a child component?

Tags: html, angular, enums, angular4-forms

I got stuck on accessing the selected value from an enum I deployed in my contact.component today. It is part of a form. Here is how I implemented the enum:

> contact.component.ts (extract of relevant code only)

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    //emum for contact list type
    export enum ContactType {
      'Select-One',
      'Information-Request',
      'Suggestion',
      'CustomerService-Request',
      'Quotation-Request',
      'Complaint',
      'UrgentCallback-Request'
    }
...
    export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
      //form property declarations
      rForm: FormGroup;
      post: any;
      keys: any[]; //for enum

      //variable declarations
      contactType = ContactType; //for enum - assignment from above nested enum class

...
      //use Constructor to specify form validation
      constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
        //enum first then string fields
        this.keys = Object.keys(this.contactType).filter(Number);

...

      //method to post submitted contact form (here is where the back end service call is made to db)
      addPost(post) {
        this.contactType = post.contactType;

...
```

So my HTML class for the contact component is as follows:

> contact.component.html (extract of relevant code only)

```
  <div *ngIf="!firstName; else forminfo">
    <fieldset>
    <form id="online_contact_form" [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)=addPost(rForm.value)>
      <div class="form-container">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>Online Contact Form</h2>
          <!--Contact Type (Enum)-->
          <p>
            <label id="contactType">Contact Type:</label>
            <select>
              <option *ngFor="let key of keys" [value]="key">{{ contactType[key] }}</option>
            </select>
          </p>
          <!--First Name-->
          <p>
            <label>First Name: <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Given/First Name here"></label>
          </p>
          <div class = "alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['firstName'].valid && rForm.controls['firstName'].touched">
              {{ alertFirstName }}
          </div>
          <!--Last Name-->
...
<!--Template for form information-->
<ng-template #forminfo>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="row">
      <h3>Many Thanks - Messsage is Sent - Details Are:</h3>
      <h4>{{ contactType }}</h4>
      <h4>First Name: {{ firstName }}</h4>
      <h4>Last Name: {{ lastName }}</h4>
      <h4>Email Address: {{ email }}</h4>
      <h4>Contact Number: {{ contactNumber }}</h4>
      <p>Comment: <br>{{ comment }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

So, the styled code above displays the enum as a dropdown list very neatly in my contact form on Chrome, Safari and Firefix. The problem I have is with the selected value, I cannot seem to access the value selected in the dropdown and add it in the template (post submit) that displays when the submit button is clicked on. Is there a method .Selected() that I can use with enums to get he selected value into a variable in Angular 4.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using ReactiveForms, but you don't have a `FormControl` to hold the value of your select.

```
this.rForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'select': []
  ...
});
```

For the html

```
<select formControlName="select">
  ...
</select>
```

Then when you call submit

```
this.contactType[this.rForm.get('select').value];
```

Comment: You bet Chris.. I tried a million way to get it to work and knew (as usual .. lol) it would come down to one or two lines of code... I passed the submited enum type `this.contactType[this.rForm.get('select').value];` into a string value and passed it into the post object and it works a treat! Also added back the `formControlName` as I had taken it out a million times yesterday and restored it.

Comment: The Enum works now in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but in Chrome & Firefox the default "Select-One" value does not show as a default dropdown value.  Will revisit this if Ive time after completing the front end.. Thanks a bunch for your help bro! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use formControlName or 2 way binding [(ngModel)]

Answer (score 0):

The string enums were introduced in TypeScript 2.4. AFAIK, Angular still doesn't support 2.4.

Comment: Thanks Yakov for the info.. I got it working per the above but it was a real hassle... a dedicated enumHelperClass() including string enums is needed for Angular me thinks.. String enums are too useful to not cater for at the framework level in my view. ASP.NET has a nice class in Razor for Enum handling post MVC 5.1 as e,g.  @Html. EnumDropDownListFor(...)